# What is the best way to model a complex role and permissions in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, permissions

I need suggestion for modeling roles and permission in rails application. In my application I have different roles and related permissions. User can have number of roles and associated permissions. Also there is provision that user can be transformed from one role to another. and on advance level there could be possibility of assignation specific permission of a particular role (customizing permission assigned of the role). Also when user can created or updated it can see specific set of roles for assignment based on which group user belongs..

Any idea how to model this in a best way which should be flexible and easy to integrate any new role and permission without affecting code